# What is the "?" and ":" sequence actually called?

Tags: c++, idioms, conditional-operator

This may be a bonehead question, but I cannot figure out what the `? exp : other_exp` sequence is called.

Example:

`int result = (true) ? 1 : 0;`

I've tried using the Google machine, but it's hard to Googilize for something without knowing what it's called.

Thanks!

Comment: Conditional operator or [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Comment: This could be googled as "question mark colon operator".

Comment: Also, StackOverflow's own search is more rigorous, and recognizes ?: characters, and can be used in similar situations.

Comment: The parentheses around `true` aren't needed.

Comment: Apart from the duplicate I just pointed to, see also [What are these called](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3257229/96780).

Comment: What book are you learning C++ from that told you about the operator without telling you its name?

Comment: @RobKennedy no book, I've seen and adopted it from code already written.

Comment: You should consider getting a book. Your local library probably has few.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is called the the conditional operator or alternativly the ternary operator as it a ternary operator (an operator which takes 3 operands (arguments)), and as it's usually the only operator, that does this.

It is also know as the inline if (iif), the ternary if or the question-mark-operator.

It is actualy a rather useful feature, as they are expressions, rather than statements, and can therefore be used, for instance in `constexpr` functions, assigments and such.

The C++ Syntax is;

```
logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

It's used as;

```
condition ? condition_is_true_expression : condition_is_false_expression
```

That is, if `condition` evaluates to `true`, the expression evaluates to `condition_is_true_expression` otherwise the expression evaluates to `condition_is_false_expression`.

So in your case, `result` would always be assigned the value `1`.

Note 1; A common mistake that one makes while working with the conditional operator, is to forget that it has a fairly low [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Note 2; Some functional languages doesn't provide this operator, as they have expression `'if...else'` constructs, such as OCaml;

```
let value = if b then 1 else 2
```

Note 3; A funny use case, which is perfectly valid is using the conditional operator, to decide, which of two variable to assign a value to.

```
(condition ? x : y) = 1;
```

Notice the parentheses are necessary, as this is really what you get without them;

```
condition ? x : (y = 1);
```

Comment: Nice explenation, very clear +1

Comment: actually, it is defined as *logical-or-expression* ? *expression* : *assignment-expression* by the standard, where the *assignment-expression* can be a *conditional-expression*, a *throw-expression* or an assigment (=, *=, += and the like)

Comment: @ArneMertz; I was clearly reading the wrong BNF, thanks for correcting, I've editted my answer.

Comment: Good explanation, more detail than I needed but clear nonetheless.

Comment: I love that you included that last note.

Answer (score 2):

They are called `shorthand if-else` or `ternary operators`.

See this [article](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/53677/) for more information.